# Defining a topology whose limit point operator equals a given function

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a set and $d:P(X)\rightarrow P(X)$ is a function with $d(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ such that for all $A,B\in P(X)$ we have

1. $d(A\cup B)\subseteq d(A)\cup d(B)$,
2. $A\subseteq B$ $\implies$ $d(A)\subseteq d(B)$,
3. for all $x\in X$, $x\in d(A)$ $\implies$ $x\in d(A\setminus\{x\})$ and
4. $d(d(A))\subseteq d(A)\cup A$.

These are all properties that the limit point operation satisfies, but here $d$ is just a function because we don't yet have a topology. Now define $\tau$ by letting $U\in \tau$ if and only if $U\subseteq X$ and $d(X\setminus U)\subseteq X\setminus U$; that is, a set $C$ is closed if and only if $d(C)\subseteq C$. It's pretty easy to see that $\tau$ is a topology on $X$ and that for $A\subseteq X$, if $A'$ denotes the set of limit points of $A$ in $(X,\tau)$, then $d(A)\subseteq A'$. I think it also follows that $d(A)\supseteq A'$, but I wonder if there is another way to see it?

Let's show that for all $A\subseteq X$ we have $A'=d(A)$. First, recall that the closure of any set $A$ is $\overline{A}=A\cup A'$, the smallest closed set that contains $A$. Notice that $A\cup d(A)$ is closed because $X\setminus (A\cup d(A))$ is open (since $d(A\cup d(A))\subseteq d(A)\cup d(d(A))\subseteq A\cup d(A)$). Thus $A\cup A'\subseteq A\cup d(A)$, but we already know $d(A)\subseteq A'$, so we have $\overline{A}=A\cup A'=A\cup d(A)$.

Now, fix a set $A\subseteq X$. To see that $A'=d(A)$, we have $x\in A'$ iff $x\in \overline{A\setminus\{x\}}$ iff $x\in (A\setminus\{x\})\cup(A\setminus \{x\})'$ iff $x\in (A\setminus \{x\})\cup d(A\setminus\{x\})$ iff $x\in d(A\setminus\{x\})$ iff $x\in d(A)$.

Is this right? Is there an easier way to see that $A'=d(A)$ for all $A\subseteq X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally see nothing wrong with your argument, and I think it's a quite direct way to show the result. Maybe be more explicit about the fact that $\overline{A}$ and $A'$ are meant within the defined topology $\tau$. I gathered as much, but other readers might not. You could also directly check the topology axioms for closed sets instead ($C$ is closed iff $d(C) \subseteq C$ etc.), which might be shorter. But I think it's OK as it stands, FWIW.